# Faceted search in PostgresQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Working with a Postgres database for an ecommerce website and we'd like to implement a faceted search.

I did some reading and appears to me that relational databases are not the best fit.

We don't really have the resources to implement something like Lucene currently, what patterns would be our best bet to start with something simple that we could later migrate to?

It is highly desirable that it works with 1mm or more records.

The facets will be collected from 3 different tables ( brands, attributes, properties ).

Here's a basic overview of the tables that we currently have, related to the facets.

- attribute_groups - id, name (ex: Color)
- attributes - id, name (ex. Red), attribute_group_id
- property_groups - id, name (ex. Material) property_group_id
- properties - id, name (ex. Wood )
- products - id, brand_id ...
- product_variants - id, product_id
- product_variants_to_attributes - product_variant_id, attribute_id
- products_to_properties - product_id, property_id
- brands - id, name

Initial thoughts

One of my  first thoughts would be to send a database query that collects all of the facets from different tables with UNION ALL, which would returns something to the lines of

| id | Facet | Value | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | Brand | Adidas | brand |
| 12 | Brand | Puma | brand |
| 6 | Color | Blue | attribute |

What worries me about this approach is that I have multiple tables to join in order to assemble the facets.

Attributes route

`products -> product_variants -> product_variants_to_attributes -> attributes -> attribute_groups`

Properties route

`products -> products_to_properties -> properties -> property_groups`

I think its safe to assume that this will not be very performant especially on one of the hottest queries of the system and because of the many different options, it would be pretty hard to cache it efficiently.

Are there any patterns for indexing the data within the context of Postgres, like adding tables for associations between a filter, attributes and products?

Its desirable for the filter to work in a way that, if I set a `product.price => 100` on the products query, I would like to get back facets only for the products that match that condition.

What are my best bets?

Here's an image from google for the desired result.

[image]

Comment: Why is `Color` an `attribute` but `Material` is a `property`? Why can't they both be `property`? Why can't `Brand` be one `property_group` also? 
Show some example data from all tables.

Comment: Attributes are variations of a product that can be selected on purchase. If you are buying a phone, it may have attributes for memory - 64 or 128GB. Properties are inherent to the product and may not be selected by the customer, for example, the material of which the phone is built

Comment: And `Brand`? An iPhone is always an Apple and a Galaxy is always a Samsung.

Comment: Brands are standalone entities with names, images, descriptions etc and are associated with Products.